# Refer =Query in a textfield in reports

Tags: ms-access, vba

I want to display a defined query ( the query result is just 1 field ) and put it into report textbox.

```
Private Sub Report_Load()
Me.txt_1 = [QUERY_Count_Lists_T0]![List_Lacznie]
End Sub
```

But i get an error couldn't locate field |1

EDIT:

Well It coudn't find my form but its there. I got

```
Me.txt_count = DLookup("Suma", "QUERY_CountGet_Lists_For") 

    SELECT count(dbo_listy.listnumb) AS Suma
    FROM dbo_listy

WHERE forwho =Forms!frm_Customers!cbo_customers.value;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot refer to a query in that way, there a few possibilities, but the best bet is [DLookUp](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ie/access-help/dlookup-function-HA001228825.aspx):

```
=DLookUp("List_Lacznie","QUERY_Count_Lists_T0")
```

You can add a where statement to the third argument, if you need one, you can even refer to a form:

```
=DLookUp("List_Lacznie","QUERY_Count_Lists_T0","forwho=Forms!frm_Customers!cbo_customers")
```

Always make sure that the textbox you use does not have the same name as a field in the recordsource for the report.

Comment: You have two completely separate things there. The query needs to work by itself, if you wish to use a query, otherwise simplify. Wait for my edit.

Comment: Basically im trying to use : [Form Popup]->Query->Generate Report:(

Comment: Referring to your next question, I suggest that the form has a button that loads the report, not the other way around.

Comment: Depending on what query is used for the report, you may not even need DLookup, a simple Count may suit.

Comment: Ok question 2. So in form onClick load raport would be better?

Comment: We can discuss is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21645822/create-a-popup-window-for-report-with-a-combobox-isnt-working-in-my-case

Comment: Yes, it would be better to have the form first. I tested the Dlookup before I posted, you need to check that the form is open and that the names are correct. When you mention an error, it is always best to give full details. I suspect that if you work with the form first, you will not need DLookUp.

Comment: Would you mind doing a simple access file with just the reference? Form->Q->Rep join the other discussion so I can approve the answer.

Comment: I think you can answer your own questions in Stackoverflow. :)

Comment: Well I can but its more clean for other people to have it separate ;) Would you be able to provide me with this example? Of the report from selectbox?