# Create a popup window for report with a combobox ( Isn't working in my case )

Tags: ms-access, vba

[image]

zoom in : https://i.stack.imgur.com/qUIDR.png
I created a form as a window with a simple combobox. I got a query that its related to with the where clause referring to the from and value of the combobox. I wrote a code in the report

```
Private Sub Report_Load()
frm.Customers.Show
End Sub
```

But somehow it opens first the query not the form itself. I mean by that the query wants me to input the `[Forms]![frm_Customers]![cbo_customers].[value]`
When I run the form alone everything opens up normally. Can you tell me why?

Query EDIT:

```
SELECT dbo_listy.listnumb, dbo_listy.id, dbo_listy.created, dbo_listy.type
FROM dbo_listy
WHERE forwho =Forms!frm_Customers!cbo_customers.value;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the form first, then use [OpenReport](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb238032%28v=office.12%29.aspx) in a command button:

```
 expression.OpenReport(ReportName, View, FilterName, _
     WhereCondition, WindowMode, OpenArgs)

 DoCmd.OpenReport "MyReport",,,"MyID=" & Me.txtID
```

Or in your case

```
 DoCmd.OpenReport "MyReport",acViewPreview,,"id=" & Me.cbo_customers
```

Note that the report should be based on the full set of data, the WHERE statement will limit it to the customer ID in Me.txtID or cbo_customers

EDIT as I said above, the query should include the full set of records, that is:

```
 SELECT dbo_listy.listnumb, 
        dbo_listy.id, 
        dbo_listy.created, 
        dbo_listy.type
 FROM dbo_listy
```

See also http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb225993(v=office.12).aspx

Comment: Ok but why it forces a print + calls for forwho inputbox

Comment: ForWho does not exist in the query you posted. I suggest you use an ID.

Comment: all seems to work tell me why it prints instat of opening the report ?

Comment: Read through the answer above with special reference to the links. You need to set the View property to acViewPreview.

Comment: I want add a extra filed that counts up the numbers and paste it in a label how should I do it with using the combobox selector? I also want to retrive the name and surname there also somehow. List generated for ID name surname

Comment: You can add numbers in a textbox in a report header or footer, eg `=Sum(This)` or `=Count(That)`, there is also a running sum.

Comment: Im bit retarded. Can you tell me how This should be replaced? Im forced to do a project in access I don't like this:P , and how to get the name surname from combobox?.column(1)+2 it will be

Comment: This and That are the names of the fields you wish to sum or count, you can refer to a column of a combobox, but it would be much better to create your query so that it contains all the data you need in a report.